# Skew-symmetricity of the Cup product

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, galois-representations, galois-cohomology

Let $f, g \in H^1(G, {\Bbb Z}/n{\Bbb Z})$ be two elements. Consider the cup-product

\begin{equation}
∪ \colon H^1(G, {\Bbb Z}/n{\Bbb Z}) \times 
H^{1}(G, {\Bbb Z}/n{\Bbb Z}) 
\to 
H^2(G, {\Bbb Z}/n{\Bbb Z}).
\end{equation}
This is defined as follows:

$f \cup g(\sigma,\tau) \colon= f(\sigma)\sigma (g(\tau)) \in {\Bbb Z}$.

### Q. How can one show that the cup-product $∪$ is skew-symmetric explicitly?
That is, $f \cup g = -g \cup f$.

Comment: Your data being rather imprecise and your definitions rather floppy, allow me to recap :

1) When considering a cohomology group $H^i(G,A)$, you must first precise the action of $G$ on $A$. Usually, with the notation $H^i(G,Z/nZ)$, the $G$-action is implicitely supposed to be trivial. So here $H^1(G$, **Z**/*n***Z**)= $Hom(G$, **Z**/*n***Z**). 
2) Your formula for the cup product, as it is written, makes believe that $f,g$ are cohomology classes, whereas they are in principle representative cocycles. Even in the case of a trivial $G$-action, the confusion would be dangerous.

Comment: . Besides, since the $G$-action is trivial, the $G$-module **Z**/*n***Z** is just the group (**Z**/*n***Z**, +). So what is the meaning of the "product" in your formula ?Besides, since the $G$-action is trivial, the $G$-module **Z**/*n***Z** is just the group (**Z**/*n***Z**, +). So what is the meaning of the "product" in your formula ? Actually, in the general definition, the cup-product is a pairing $H^i(G,A) \times H^j(G,b) \to H^{i+j}(G, A \otimes B)$. In the case here, $A=B=$ **Z**/*n***Z**, and you implicitely identified $A\otimes B$ with **Z**/*n***Z**

Comment: 3) So here, $f,g$ will denote 1-cocycles (or homomorphisms since $G$ acts trivially) with values in **Z**/*n***Z** (not in **Z**), and you must show that the 2-cocycle $(s, t) \to f(s)\otimes g(t) - g(s)\otimes f(t)$ is a 2-coboundary.